# Best Practice Max Size For Cassandra Columns & Maps

Tags: cassandra

I have modeled some data in Cassandra where rows have some columns types of List with several hundred values as well as Map<int,UDT> where the UDT type has about 5 fields and that map has several hundred key/value pairs as well.

The domain is capturing several attributes and other things for a stock during each market session and the alternative to this modeling approach would result in thousands of partitions being created each day instead of unique keys in a Map, I am trying to find the answer if having Map and List columns in tables with sizes referenced above is anti-pattern or if this is something that Cassandra will handle fine over the long-term. I do not index any of the List or map key values and also in this approach the table partitions are bounded to roughly 100MB of data.

Straight forward question, I hope someone can answer, I apologize if this is a duplicate question have not seen any knowledge on the Internet or StackOverflow